# c# tree view, select the child node when select he parent node

Tags: c#, tree

i create one tree view. bind this tree view with a database.

I want that if i select the parent node, all the child nodes should automatically selected.

in c# what can i do??

Answer (score 3):

This is something like you want:

```
// Updates all child tree nodes recursively.
private void CheckAllChildNodes(TreeNode treeNode, bool nodeChecked)
{
   foreach(TreeNode node in treeNode.Nodes)
   {
      node.Checked = nodeChecked;
      if(node.Nodes.Count > 0)
      {
         // If the current node has child nodes, call the CheckAllChildsNodes method recursively.
         this.CheckAllChildNodes(node, nodeChecked);
      }
   }
}

// NOTE   This code can be added to the BeforeCheck event handler instead of the AfterCheck event.
// After a tree node's Checked property is changed, all its child nodes are updated to the same value.
private void node_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
   // The code only executes if the user caused the checked state to change.
   if(e.Action != TreeViewAction.Unknown)
   {
      if(e.Node.Nodes.Count > 0)
      {
         /* Calls the CheckAllChildNodes method, passing in the current 
         Checked value of the TreeNode whose checked state changed. */
         this.CheckAllChildNodes(e.Node, e.Node.Checked);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'selected', do you mean with checkboxes? If you only mean 'highlighted', then this goes against the design of tree controls - only one branch / leaf can be highlighted at any one time (to show the one you currently have selected). If you mean that putting a check in the parent branch's box also puts a check in all children's boxes, then you need to respond to the event that is fired when you click a branch, check the checked state, and manually walk the branch's children to set their checked state.

Answer (score 0):

The above code does not work reliably - it is copy / paste code from the MSDN AfterCheck event topic however the event is not fired reliably on double click - you need to mix it code that disables double click - this is what I found as a workaround in MSDN:

```
public class MyTreeView : TreeView
{
    #region Constructors

    public MyTreeView()
    {
    }

    #endregion

    #region Overrides

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        // Suppress WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK on checkbox
        if (m.Msg == 0x0203 && CheckBoxes && IsOnCheckBox(m))
        {
            m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
        }
        else
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Double-click check

    private int GetXLParam(IntPtr lParam)
    {
        return lParam.ToInt32() & 0xffff;
    }

    private int GetYLParam(IntPtr lParam)
    {
        return lParam.ToInt32() >> 16;
    }

    private bool IsOnCheckBox(Message m)
    {
        int x = GetXLParam(m.LParam);
        int y = GetYLParam(m.LParam);
        TreeNode node = GetNodeAt(x, y);
        if (node == null)
            return false;
        int iconWidth = ImageList == null ? 0 : ImageList.ImageSize.Width;
        int right = node.Bounds.Left - 4 - iconWidth;
        int left = right - CHECKBOX_WIDTH;
        return left <= x && x <= right;
    }

    const int CHECKBOX_WIDTH = 12;

    #endregion
```